# Webpack doesn't bundle all functions in my JS file

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I recently integrated Webpack to my project to build bundles for the JS files on my website. After fixing a few small issues, I was able to get the bundle to be built. Upon checking in the browser, one of the Javascript codes threw the below error.

[image]

Upon checking, I realized the addComment.moveform was causing the problem.

[image]

So, I checked the generated bundle and realized the definition of the variable addComment has not been pushed to the bundle. Is there a reason why Javascript written as below would not get bundled? Without Webpack throwing an error about it?

```
 /**
 * 'Comment Reply' to each comment.
 * This script moves the Add Comment section to the position below the appropriate comment.
 * Modified from Wordpress https://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js
 * Released under the GNU General Public License - https://wordpress.org/about/gpl/
 */
var addComment = {
  moveForm: function(commId, parentId, respondId, postId) {
    var div,
      element,
      style,
      cssHidden,
      t = this,
      comm = t.I(commId),
      respond = t.I(respondId),
      cancel = t.I("cancel-comment-reply-link"),
      parent = t.I("comment-replying-to"),
      post = t.I("comment-post-slug"),
      commentForm = respond.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];

    if (!comm || !respond || !cancel || !parent || !commentForm) {
      return;
    }

    t.respondId = respondId;
    postId = postId || false;

    if (!t.I("sm-temp-form-div")) {
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = "sm-temp-form-div";
      div.style.display = "none";
      respond.parentNode.insertBefore(div, respond);
    }

    comm.parentNode.insertBefore(respond, comm.nextSibling);
    if (post && postId) {
      post.value = postId;
    }
    parent.value = parentId;
    cancel.style.display = "";

    cancel.onclick = function() {
      var t = addComment,
        temp = t.I("sm-temp-form-div"),
        respond = t.I(t.respondId);

      if (!temp || !respond) {
        return;
      }

      t.I("comment-replying-to").value = "0";
      temp.parentNode.insertBefore(respond, temp);
      temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);
      this.style.display = "none";
      this.onclick = null;
      return false;
    };

    /*
     * Set initial focus to the first form focusable element.
     */
    document.getElementById("comment-form-message").focus();

    /*
     * Return false so that the page is not redirected to HREF.
     */
    return false;
  },

  I: function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably because of dead code elimination a.k.a. [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/): if Webpack notices that a particular function is not being used, it just leaves it out to produce a smaller bundle. But Webpack only knows about functions being called *from JavaScript*, not from your event handlers that are hardcoded in HTML.

The simplest way to fix this is to play by Webpack's rules, and attach your event handlers through JavaScript instead. This is better practice anyway, for [various reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278960/javascript-inline-event-handling-versus-external-jquery-event-handlers).

If you need to pass data to the event handler (as you're doing here), you can use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the element and read out the data in your event handler function.